# How to parse Json object

Tags: json, angularjs, servlets

I am  sending  json object from  angularjs controller  and collecting in HttpServlet dopost() method.Request  is  sent  successfully  but  i am  unable to  parse that  json object.

```
Html code and  angularjs code

<body ng-controller='myctrl'>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" ng-model="fname"/>
 <input type="button"  value="Click" ng-click="chk()">
<script>
 function  myctrl($scope,$http)
    {
      $scope.chk=function(){
       $http.post("http://localhost:7001/Angularjsprac/test",$scope.fname).success(function     (data){
            });

       } }
```

```
      Servlet code

     @WebServlet("/test")
     public class PracticeController extends HttpServlet {


@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    StringBuffer sb= new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader  reader=req.getReader();
    String line=null;
    while( (line=reader.readLine())!=null)
    {
      sb.append(line);  

    }
    JSONParser parser= new JSONParser();
    JSONObject joUser = null;
     try
        {
        joUser = (JSONObject) parser.parse(sb.toString());
        }
     catch(ParseException E)
     {
         System.out.println("parse exception");
         E.printStackTrace();
     }
    String user = (String) joUser.get("fname");
     System.out.println("user"+user);
     resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.write("A new user " + user + " has been created.");
        out.flush();
        out.close();

}
```

}

I am getting  error  in parsing.

---------------------------Updated-----------

```
     Error


 17:49:51,287 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-7001-1) parse exception

17:49:51,288 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-7001-1) Unexpected character (s) at position 0.

17:49:51,289 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-7001-1)  at org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Unknown Source)

17:49:51,289 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-7001-1)  at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.nextToken(Unknown Source)

17:49:51,290 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-7001-1)  at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)

17:49:51,291 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-7001-1)  at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)

17:49:51,292 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-7001-1)  at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)

17:49:51,293 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-7001-1)  at controllers.PracticeController.doPost(PracticeController.java:32)

17:49:51,294 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-7001-1)  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)

17:49:51,294 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-7001-1)  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)

17:49:51,295 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-7001-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)

17:49:51,296 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-7001-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)

17:49:51,297 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-7001-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)

17:49:51,298 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-7001-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)

17:49:51,299 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-7001-1)  at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)

17:49:51,300 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-7001-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)

17:49:51,301 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-7001-1)  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)

17:49:51,302 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-7001-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)

17:49:51,303 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-7001-1)  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)

17:49:51,304 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-7001-1)  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)

17:49:51,305 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-7001-1)  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)

17:49:51,305 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-7001-1)  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)

17:49:51,306 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-7001-1)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


   17:49:51,306 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/Angularjsprac].[controllers.PracticeController]] (http--0.0.0.0-7001-1) Servlet.service() for servlet controllers.PracticeController threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at controllers.PracticeController.doPost(PracticeController.java:39) [classes:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
```

Comment: What does "unable to parse JSON" object mean.  Are you getting errors?  What are the errors?

Comment: You are not sending any JSON object. You are sending a string.

Comment: @saurabh Hey take a look at my answer....its very easy..

Answer (score 0):

you are not sending Json objects, try using `angular.toJson($scope.fname)` in the post request